# Which Raspbian package contains the cdio C++ bindings?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, packages

I can't find them in [libcdio-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libcdio-dev), and a search for the most important header file, [cdio.hpp](https://github.com/cisco-open-source/libcdio/blob/master/include/cdio%2B%2B/cdio.hpp), in the Debian package catalog gave no results. A `libcdio++` package seems not to exist either.

Doesthis mean I've gotta compile `libcdio` with the C++ bindings from source? Does anybody know that? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to get Bluetooth/Bluetooth.h for Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/where-to-get-bluetooth-bluetooth-h-for-raspberry-pi) Hint: you can't find it becase the Linux file is actually called `cdio.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to build cdio++ from scratch, but at least it worked afterwards.